# Restore Google Maps state in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I am creating an application in which I have a fragment that contains a map. When the user clicks on the search bar, another fragment is displayed (Search Fragment) in which I handle all the search logic, including displaying suggestions. When the search is complete, I add a marker at the point that corresponds to the search query. However, the fragment is recreated and the `onMapReady()` is also called. Thus in the process of moving the camera to where I want to place the marker, there is a glitch which does not show a smooth transition from the `SearchFragment` to the `MapsFragment`. Is there a way to save the map state to avoid the `onMapReadyCallback` so that the transition from the `SearchFragment` to the `MapsFragment` becomes seamless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set [`setRetainInstance(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#setRetainInstance(boolean)) in your `MapsFragment`.

Java:

```
public class MyMapFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }
}
```

Kotlin:

```
class MyMapsFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        retainInstance = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had forgotten to set `setRetainInstance(true)`. I really appreciate